# capistrano заливает данные в development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Использую связку **nginx**+**passenger**. Во всех настройках пишу что заливаться будет в production, однако когда захожу на сайт пишет

**'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)**

Вот настройки

**Capfile**

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require "capistrano/rails"
require "capistrano/passenger"
require "capistrano/rbenv"


Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
```

**Deploy.rb**

```
lock "3.7.1"

set :application, "rifc"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:users/rifc.git"
set :user, "deployer" #
set :password, "pass"
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.3.3"
set :stage, :production


set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/www"

set :migration_role, :db
set :migration_servers, -> { primary(fetch(:migration_role)) }


append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"
set :default_env, { path: "~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" }
```

**production.rb**

```
server '88.99.111.111',user: 'deployer', roles: %w{app db web}
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

Comment: как запускаете **capistrano**?

Comment: cap production deploy

Comment: а как у вас настроен Passenger? добавьте это в вопрос.

Comment: У вас там просто не указана переменная среды, которая отвечает за environment. Скорее всего. И используется development, по умолчанию.